# Why don't pandas .unique and .loc selection work together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why don't pandas .unique and .loc selection work together?

[image: 1]

How can it be that an empty list is returned to me, although .unique finds the element "CH" as shown in the picture, but .loc does not?

```
    for farm in data["farm_y"].unique():
        plot_data = data.loc[data["farm_y"] == farm]
```

Comment: From just this code snippet, it's hard to figure out the issue. It sure seems like plot_data should not be empty. Can you show the content of `data` (at least partially) and/or create a self-contained MWE (minimum working example) that shows this behaviour?

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Answer (score 0):

to be able to loop over subgroups use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
for farm, plot_data in data.groupby('farm_y'):
    # do stuff
```